# Why does normalizing difference score>0.25 indicates selection bias which cannot be corrected by regression?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, causality, propensity-scores, selection-bias

I am reading Propensity Score Analysis(2014) by Guo and Fraser chapter 1 section 4. Denote $\Delta_X$ normalizing difference score of covariate $X$.

"Following Imbens and Wooldridge, a $\Delta_X$ exceeding .25 is an indication that selection bias exists and linear regression method tend to be sensitive to model specification... researcher should consider employing corrective approach other than regression, or at least perform corrective analysis in conjunction with regression analysis."

Q1. Why does normalizing difference score>0.25 indicates selection bias? There is no explicit testing here.

Q2. Why naive regression adjustment is not sufficient under selection bias assumption? What is the theoretical justification?

Q3. One could do a two stage model modeling treatment by logistic regression and then outcome estimated based upon treatment estimated. Is this sufficient to remove selection bias? The selection bias might be accounted by logistic regression if the corresponding covariate is included.